# Java 2D Array; Variable Row & Column Length from File Input

Tags: java, arrays

For this intro-level assignment, I have to set up a 2D multidimensional array from a file and from a `double[][]` a and apply several methods to them. For now, I'm mostly concerned with simply initializing the arrays. I'm trying to figure out a way to take a test file, read the first int as the number of rows, the first integer of each line as the number of columns per row, and each double as a member of the array.

```
 public class MDArray
    {
        static int rowCount;
        static int columnCount;
        private static double[][] mdarray = new double[rowCount][columnCount];

    public MDArray(double[][] a)
    {
        mdarray = a;
    }

    public MDArray(String file)
    {
        Scanner input = null;
        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("ragged.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(input.hasNextDouble())
        {
            rowCount = input.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                columnCount = input.nextInt();
                for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    double value = input.nextDouble();
                    mdarray[i][j] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isRagged()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mdarray.length; i++)
        {
            int rowLength1 = mdarray.length;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < mdarray.length; j++)
            {
                int rowLength2 = mdarray.length;
                if(rowLength1 != rowLength2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfRows()
    {
        int numRows = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < mdarray.length; i++)
        {
            numRows++;
        }
        return numRows;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfCols()
    {
        int numCols = 0;
        for(int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < mdarray.length; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < mdarray[i].length; k++)
            {
                if(mdarray[i].length > mdarray[j].length)
                {
                    numCols++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numCols;
    }

    public static double getValAt(int i, int j)
    {
        if(i > mdarray.length || j > mdarray[i].length)
        {
            double invalid = Double.NaN;
            return invalid;
        }
        double valAt = mdarray[i][j];
        return valAt;
    }

    public static void sort(boolean byColumn)
    {
        if(isRagged() == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Ragged arrays cannot be sorted by column.");
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < mdarray.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < mdarray[i].length; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = j + 1; k < mdarray[i].length; k++)
                    {
                        if(mdarray[i][j] < mdarray[i][k])
                        {
                            double temp = mdarray[i][j];
                            mdarray[i][k] = mdarray[i][j];
                            mdarray[i][j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int hamming(boolean byColumn)
    {
        int hamVal = 0;
        if(isRagged() == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Ragged arrays cannot be sorted by column.");
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < mdarray.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < mdarray[i].length; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = j + 1; k < mdarray[i].length; k++)
                    {
                        if(mdarray[i][j] < mdarray[i][k])
                        {
                            double temp = mdarray[i][j];
                            mdarray[i][k] = mdarray[i][j];
                            mdarray[i][j] = temp;
                            hamVal++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return hamVal;
    }

    public static double[] max()
    {
        double[] maxVal = new double[mdarray.length];
        for(int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < maxVal.length; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < mdarray[i].length; k++)
                {
                    if(mdarray[i][k] > mdarray[j][k])
                    {
                        maxVal = mdarray[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        return maxVal;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String arrayString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < mdarray.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < mdarray[i].length; j++)
            {
                arrayString += ", " + mdarray[i][j];
            }
            arrayString = arrayString + "/n";
        }
        return arrayString;
    }
}
```

This was the file I was testing the MDArray(String file) with:

> 3
>
> 2 4.1 8.9
>
> 5 9.5 2.0 7.3 2.1 8.9
>
> 3 1.3 5.2 3.4

I think the problem is that the `rowCount` and `columnCount` integers are not initialized, but I'm not sure how to initialize them to a variable length with basic array skills. This is also affecting the other constructor as well. Being an intro-level course, I am not supposed to use more advanced techniques such as `ArrayList`. In addition, I can't verify if the methods are correct, since I don't have an array to test them with.

EDIT: While I did implement many of the suggestions in the answers, such as changing everything to non-static and other changes, I'm still getting a `NullPointerException` for the line `mdarray[i][j] = input.nextDouble();.` I assume it has to do with the private `double[][] mdarray`, which is required in the assignment specifications. Now I'm trying to find a way to initialize it such that it can be overridden in the later methods.

Comment: the only way i can think of, realizing it with an normal array would be to read the ll lines first, get the highest number for the columns, then initialize the array and read the file again to add the values and either set the empty values to 0 or null

Comment: you should allocate the arrays while reading the file.

Comment: BTW, why are all the fields static?

Comment: @MauricePerry Previous exercises and examples in this course had used static methods in similar contexts.

Comment: @JonathanGruver well it's a shame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the array in your constructor, since that's when you know the dimensions :

```
public MDArray(String file)
{
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("ragged.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    rowCount = input.nextInt(); 
    mdarray = new double[rowCount][]; // init the array
    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        columnCount = input.nextInt();
        mdarray[i] = new double[columnCount]; // init the current row
        for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            mdarray[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize your arrays by putting the amount of rows and columns on the first 2 lines of your multidimensional array, if i had 10 rows and 12 columns i could do something like this:

```
    public void arrayStuff() {
    File fileToRead = new File("YOUR LINK HERE");
    String[][] data;


    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToRead))) {

        String line;
        data = new String[Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine())][Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine())];
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // read the rest here..
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using an AutoCloseable (which is why the try is between these ()'s, but this is so that i don't have to close it afterwards.

Basically, first i read the amount of rows there are and then the amount of columns there are, so if i had this file:

```
10
12
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h i j
```

It'd be able to read all of this, because the amount of rows and columns were defined in the file.

Comment: That would work in general, but given the specifications of the assignment, I won't be able to use this. I think the file has to be set up in the way the assignment describes because not every row is the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the fields rowCount and columnCount: you can remove them

The mdarray field should be non-static, so should be the methods that use them (if it was a utility class, you wouldn't have any constructor)

The arrays can be created while reading the file:

```
Scanner input = null;
try
{
    input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("ragged.txt"));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    System.exit(0);
}
int rowCount = input.nextInt();
mdarray = new double[rowCount][];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    int columnCount = input.nextInt();
    mdarray[i] = new double[columnCount];
    for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        mdarray[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

methods getNumberOfRows() and getNumberOfCols() count be much simpler:

```
public int getNumberOfRows()
{
    return mdarray.length;
}

public int getNumberOfCols() {
    int result = 0;
    for (double[] col: mdarray) {
        if (col.length > result) {
            result = col.length;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In getValueAt(), the test is wrong; it should be:

```
if(i >= mdarray.length || j >= mdarray[i].length)
```